# every other text styling

Tags: css

I want to make my website news styled.

```
first news : red
second news : blue
third news : red
fourth news : blue
```

and other like that.
color should be every other text changed.

how can I do that? because one div is used for all news! and one css.

Comment: Learn basics about css classes and their use? This is pretty basic stuff. And you should show some code if you want to get help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the news in seperate elements in a container like so:

```
<div id="news">
    <span>Some news 1</span>
    <span>Some news 2</span>
    <span>Some news 3</span>
    <span>Some news 4</span>
</div>
```

Then you can simply style every other child element using this CSS:

```
#news span:nth-child(2n) {
    color: #f00; // 1st, 3rd, 5th...
}

#news span:nth-child(2n+1) {
    color: #00f; // 2nd, 4th, 6th...
}
```

Comment: Even and odd would also work but I wanted to show you that you can specify a certain 'pattern definition' and get pretty much anything you need.

Comment: there is a problem. my spans are not 4. only 1 span. but it is repeated by php. I mean in html I have only 1 span. but php uses it for 4 news.

Answer (score 3):

You could use JQuery.

For example if the news items are in a list you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu li:nth-child(even)').addClass('blue-link');
  $('#menu li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('red-link');
});
```

This will set for example, the odd numbered links (as in 1st, 3rd etc..) links to red and the even numbers (2nd, 4th,6th etc) links to blue.

For this example the html would be:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>first news</li>
<li>second news</li>
<li>third news</li>
<li>fourth news</li>
</ul>
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwCaL/

Answer (score 2):

If the website is just a static website I would style like this;

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li class="red">News 1</li>
   <li class="blue">News 2</li>
   <li class="red">News 3</li>
   <li class="blue">News 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
   color:red;
}
.blue {
   color:blue;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

*HTML:*

```
<ul>
   <span class="red"><li>News 1</li></span>
   <span class="blue"><li>News 2</li></span>
   <span class="red"><li>News 3</li></span>
   <span class="blue"><li>News 4</li></span>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
.red {
   color: red;
}
.blue {
   color: blue;
}
```